# How to "PRE-PROCESS" ajax call before showing the mvc view?

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, rest

I'm not so expert with ajax, so I find it hard to look for the better answer. I've tried creating separate ".js" file that contains the call for rest service (for validation of user session), but it doesn't work.

My goal is to validate user session before loading my views (in MVC). The only way to use the logic of validating the given session with the database is to call a rest service via url using ajax.

This code works well (inside Home View):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.get('@Url.Action("GetSession", "Auth")', function (getdata) {
            if (getdata.UserID && getdata.SessionID && getdata.SourceIP) {
                $.post('http://website.com/Rest/Authenticate/ValidateUserSession', JSON.stringify(getdata), function (response) {
                    if (response == false) { window.location.replace('@Url.Action("SignUp", "Auth")'); }
                });
            } else {
                window.location.replace('@Url.Action("SignUp", "Auth")');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<h2>
    Home</h2>

    @*The content here should not appear, unless session is validated.*@
```

The only problem is that, the process of validation takes 3 to 5 seconds, so the user sees the Home page before the ajax call returns the result whether the validation was successful or not. If validation/response returns `false` it will redirect to sigup page.

I don't know what is the best practice with this process. For now I jsut don't want the Home view show  to the user unless session is validated. Hope I'd explain it well. Please suggest if you have the better idea.

Additional info:

If possible, I like doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!validated()){
       window.location.replace('@Url.Action("SignUp", "Auth")');
    }
</script>
<h2>
    Home</h2>

    @*The content here should not appear, unless session is validated.*@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why can't you consume the rest service at server side ? Technically there should be no reason for not being able to do that. Here's a tutorial discussing exactly that : http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/03/22/accessing-a-asp-net-webapi-rest-service-from-asp-net-mvc/

That should take care of everything. If for some reason that's not possible for you, then you can do the following,

1. Make your home page a partial view.
2. Instead of loading home page, load an empty page with processing icon (or whatever message you want to show.)
3. Talk to the REST service and if got the reply then load Home page's partial view using JQuery else load sign up partial view.

Here's an article discussing how to load MVC partial views using JQuery: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34221/JQuery-Partial-Views-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: That was a good article, but I have to maintain the call of services without refreshing the page. I will try that partial view. Thanks!